# Snowflake OR condition inside the ON clause is only working on one field even when the other exists

Tags: sql, merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

I am getting data from dynamic source, where 2 fields could exists within the data or only one of them.

Those fields are `FACILITY_ID` and `BLOCK`.

Some data has only BLOCK, and some has both, and I need to do a `MERGE INTO` to add what is available into `HUB_LOCATION`.

Some data will come like that:

[image]

And some would have only `BLOCK` and some would have both:

[image]

I tried this query:

```
MERGE INTO HUB_LOCATION HL
  USING (SELECT md5(CONCAT_WS('', 'FACILITY', OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*):FACILITY_ID)) AS FACILITY_HKEY,
     md5(CONCAT_WS('', 'BLOCK', OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*):BLOCK)) AS BLOCK_HKEY, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*):FACILITY_ID AS FACILITY_ID, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*):BLOCK AS BLOCK FROM TEMP_TABLE ) ST 
  ON (md5(CONCAT_WS('', 'FACILITY', ST.FACILITY_ID)) = HL.LOCATION_HKEY OR md5(CONCAT_WS('', 'BLOCK', ST.BLOCK)) = HL.LOCATION_HKEY ) 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED AND ST.FACILITY_HKEY IS NOT NULL THEN 
      INSERT (LOCATION_HKEY, LOAD_DT, RECORD_SRC, LOCATION_VALUE, LOCATION_TYPE) 
      VALUES (md5(CONCAT_WS('', 'FACILITY', ST.FACILITY_ID)), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'ONA', ST.FACILITY_ID, 'FACILITY') 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED AND ST.BLOCK IS NOT NULL THEN
      INSERT (LOCATION_HKEY, LOAD_DT, RECORD_SRC, LOCATION_VALUE, LOCATION_TYPE) 
      VALUES (md5(CONCAT_WS('', 'BLOCK', ST.BLOCK)), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'ONA', ST.BLOCK, 'BLOCK');
```

This merge statement will only work when there is only one of both fields.

Within the `ON` clause I tried to change `OR` to `AND` but the script ran non stop.

Comment: I'm not clear on why you're using using `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*):BLOCK` instead of just `BLOCK` and similar for `FACILITY_ID`? I'm also not clear why your first `WHEN NOT MATCHED` is checking `FACILITY_HKEY` for null instead of `FACILITY_ID` -- though the MD5 will be null if the input is null anyway.

Comment: I don't know if the field exists in the table. This function will set it to null if not exist.

Comment: Got it now... I thought the fields always existed, just could be null. I'll check on this later if no one has answered by then. Another question -- are you sure it's not possible to match both conditions? In other words, is it possible to a) have both fields in the table and b) both are not null? It appears from the sample tables the answer is yes. In that case, you probably want to write the conditions so that only one matches. In this case, both will match.

Comment: @GregPavlik no it is not possible to match at all, if facility and block exists, block will be a part of the whole facility so their values could not be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced what it appears you're doing and the merge is working. The issue is the test for the first table and second table are using the same values that get matched. That inserts 0 rows from the `when not matched` clause. If you make a trivial change to the values, the merge works. If you need to update them if matched, you can add a clause for that. Here's all I did with the change to the second table to make the changes not match:

```
create or replace table HUB_LOCATION(LOCATION_HKEY string, LOAD_DT date, RECORD_SRC string, LOCATION_VALUE string, LOCATION_TYPE string);

create or replace table TEMP_TABLE(id int, facility_id string, "name" string);
insert into TEMP_TABLE (id, facility_id, "name") values (1, '1A', 'xyz'), (2, '1A', 'abc'), (3, '2C', 'ac');

create or replace table TEMP_TABLE(id int, facility_id string, "name" string, block string);
insert into TEMP_TABLE (id, facility_id, "name", block) values (1, '1Ax', 'xyz', 'B1'), (2, '1Ay', 'abc', 'B2'), (3, '2Cz', 'ac', 'B3');


MERGE INTO HUB_LOCATION HL
  USING (SELECT md5(CONCAT_WS('', 'FACILITY', OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*):FACILITY_ID)) AS FACILITY_HKEY,
     md5(CONCAT_WS('', 'BLOCK', OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*):BLOCK)) AS BLOCK_HKEY, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*):FACILITY_ID AS FACILITY_ID, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*):BLOCK AS BLOCK FROM TEMP_TABLE ) ST 
  ON (md5(CONCAT_WS('', 'FACILITY', ST.FACILITY_ID)) = HL.LOCATION_HKEY OR md5(CONCAT_WS('', 'BLOCK', ST.BLOCK)) = HL.LOCATION_HKEY ) 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED AND ST.FACILITY_HKEY IS NOT NULL THEN 
      INSERT (LOCATION_HKEY, LOAD_DT, RECORD_SRC, LOCATION_VALUE, LOCATION_TYPE) 
      VALUES (md5(CONCAT_WS('', 'FACILITY', ST.FACILITY_ID)), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'ONA', ST.FACILITY_ID, 'FACILITY') 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED AND ST.BLOCK IS NOT NULL THEN
      INSERT (LOCATION_HKEY, LOAD_DT, RECORD_SRC, LOCATION_VALUE, LOCATION_TYPE) 
      VALUES (md5(CONCAT_WS('', 'BLOCK', ST.BLOCK)), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'ONA', ST.BLOCK, 'BLOCK');
      
select * from HUB_LOCATION;
```